# Magento Programmatically Edit Order Payment

Tags: magento

I need to make a change of payment method to an order after it is placed.  I have the order ID ($orderID), the order object ($order), a proper payment object, etc.

$service->retrievePaymentType() Returns the payment in the form of Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment

All of this happens in an extension of Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage

Does anybody know how I would go about doing this?

```
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderID);

    $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $this->getQuote());

    // Update Saved Order Payment Method

    // $order->getPaymentsCollection()->clear();

    $order->setPayment($service->retrievePaymentType());

    $order->getPaymentsCollection()->save();

    $order->save();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The function "$service->retrievePaymentType()" from Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote just does the following: 
 return $this->_convertor->paymentToOrderPayment($quote->getPayment());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I had to do a direct SQL query, which is not Magento spec, but it gets the job done.  If someone want's the code, leave me a comment, and I will dig it up.

Thanks though!

**EDIT:**

I managed to in fact get this working with Magento API:

```
    // The payment type I want to change the target order to
    $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $this->getQuote()); 


    $payment = $service->retrievePaymentType();

    $paymentData = $payment->getData();
    $oldPayment = $order->getAllPayments();
    $oldPayment = $oldPayment[0];

    foreach ($paymentData as $n => $v) {
         $oldPayment->setData($n,$v);
    }
```

It is a little bit hackish, but pretty effective.

Comment: Including the code in your answer would be a good idea for sure.